# Why is my isAnnotationPresent method not working eventhough the Annotation has a RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME?

Tags: java, events, system

I am trying to implement an Annotation based Event System for my OpenGL Game Engine. I apply the @EventListener Annotation on the method which I want to be called like this:

```
@EventListener(type = Type.COLLISION)
public void OnCollision(CollisionEvent data)
{
    System.out.println("HI");
}
```

The class in which this method sits implements an Empty Interface:

```
public class Sprite implements EventHandler
```

The EventDispatcher class:

```
public class EventDispatcher
{
private static List<EventHandler> registered = new ArrayList<EventHandler>();

public static void register(EventHandler EventHandler)
{
    if (!registered.contains(EventHandler))
    {
        registered.add(EventHandler);
    }
}

public static void unregister(EventHandler EventHandler)
{
    if (registered.contains(EventHandler))
    {
        registered.remove(EventHandler);
    }
}

public static List<EventHandler> getRegistered()
{
    return registered;
}

public static void dispatch(final Event event)
{
    new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            call(event);
        }
    }.start();
}

private static void call(final Event event)
{
    for (EventHandler registered : getRegistered())
    {
        Method[] methods = registered.getClass().getMethods();

        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Annotation Being Checked");
            if (methods[i].isAnnotationPresent(EventListener.class))
            {
                System.out.println("Has Annotation");
                Class<?>[] methodParams = methods[i].getParameterTypes();
                if (methodParams.length < 1)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!event.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(methodParams[0].getSimpleName()))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                try
                {
                    methods[i].invoke(registered.getClass().newInstance(), event);
                } catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    System.err.println(exception);
                }
            } else System.out.println("No Annotation");
        }
    }
}
}
```

But when I run the program, It always prints out

Annotation Being Checked
No Annotation

multiple Times.

Can someone help? If more information is needed, please ask and I will edit the Question.

Comment: Maybe add more debug output (method names, actual class name, ...) to see what’s going on

Comment: I will try it and tell you.

Comment: I saw that OnCollision was being checked and it still says there is no Annotation. Heres the output for OnCollision:                                                                                 --OnCollision
--Annotation Being Checked
--No Annotation

Comment: Add the class name as well please

Comment: Output was: `class com.pixel.SpriteTest`

Comment: Are you sure you’re checking for the correct EventListener class? You might have imported a wrong one on accident.

Comment: There is only one EventListener Annotation and it is in the same package. So no need to import the class for the EventDispatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup a project based on your example and it's working fine. You will however see some "No Annotation" messages as your code evaluates all methods of the `Sprite` event handler. Even if you don't implement any additional methods other than `OnCollision` each class will inherit default methods from Object such as `equals`, `hashCode` or `toString`.

**Test class**:

```java
public class SpriteTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventDispatcher.register(new Sprite());

        CollisionEvent collisionEvent = new CollisionEvent();
        EventDispatcher.dispatch(collisionEvent);
    }
}
```

Apart from that there are some obvious flaws in your code:

- Don't use stateful static members (EventDispatcher.registered) unless you know what you're doing and are aware of the multithreading aspects that come with it
- You store instances of `EventHandler` but only use the class information and create a new instance on the fly - why not register the class instead of an instance directly
- You fork new Threads for each to be dispatched event. This is very bad practice as thread creation is a costly operation. Use a thread pool instead and submit runnables or callables
- You check if the class' simple names match to see if a handler method is applicable. This will break when using inheritance and should be replaced by `Class.isAssignableFrom`
- In general usage of annotations here is questionable. You're probably better off using dedicated interfaces for the different event types. Instead of a generic `EventHandler` there could be a `CollisionEventHandler` and so on...

**Rough implementation idea**

```
public interface CollisionEventHandler extends EventHandler {
  void onCollision(CollisionEvent event);  
}

public class Sprite implements CollisionEventHandler {
  public void onCollision(CollisionEvent data) {
    System.out.println("HI");
  }
}

public class EventDispatcher {
  ...

  static void call(final CollisionEvent event) {
    getRegistered().stream()
          .filter(handler -> handler instanceof CollisionEventHandler)
          .map(handler -> (CollisionEventHandler) handler)
          .forEach(handler -> handler.onCollision(event));
  }
}
```

To handle different types of events you will need different call/dispatch methods. Maybe you can use the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) (though I'm not a fan of it).

Comment: Thank you for the Answer. Can you elaborate on that last point please? I thought that using Annotations would be acceptable here... Maybe if you have the time, could you show me a better implementation of an event system??

Comment: @PixelRifts Did you solve your issue in the first place?

Comment: Yes the issue is resolved but I thought maybe you know a better way to implement this since it is my first time making a Event System...

Comment: @PixelRifts, see my updates in the answer. If your problem is resolved, maybe either update your question or, if my answer solved the problem, upvote and accept the answer.